# Devise - one user type is unable to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

Has anyone seen an issue where one user model can log in but the other can not log in? Our devise setup is fairly vanilla, and the issue is only present on production.

We have an Admin and a User model, the User model is able to login ok, but the admin model is not.

I have confirmed the admin credentials are actually valid with:

```
admin.valid_for_authentication? { admin.valid_password?("the password") }
```

But when you try and log in it still throws an error:

Completed 401 Unauthorized

Comment: What error does it throws? And could you share the logs of the login action when an admin tries to log in?

Comment: Going to try and overwrite the controller to put some debuggging in there, it might be a conflict with another gem, but very odd that users are ok, just admins having an issue

Comment: Also check for any `before_action` on the logs/code which may restrict the `admin` login with some condition not being satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I had one user with a custom route:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: "sessions"
  }
```

Adding the same custom route for the admin user fixes this issue, however, the controller does not touch the authentication methods, so very odd.